# Add a tag for blekko?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-creation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we please have the [foo] tag on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-so)

I am a low-reputation newcomer. I'd like to have a 'blekko' tag on Stack Overflow, and it was suggested on Twitter that I ask here, giving a list of questions it might apply to.

These questions are specifically about our API:

- [Schedule API calls to 1/second limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595650/schedule-api-calls-to-1-second-limit)
- [Displaying results from search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311347/displaying-results-from-search-api)
- [Python CGI Script (using XML & mindom) returns unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680643/python-cgi-script-using-xml-mindom-returns-unexpected-results)
- [Python CGI Script (using XML & mindom) cannot extract null data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691666/python-cgi-script-using-xml-mindom-cannot-extract-null-data)

These feature blekko prominently in the answers:

- [Is there a search engine that support regular expression search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119065/is-there-a-search-engine-that-support-regular-expression-search)
- [What search engines have full-featured API's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010106/what-search-engines-have-full-featured-apis)
- [Is there a blog search api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717351/is-there-a-blog-search-api)
- [Statistics about HTML versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148497/statistics-about-html-versions)

Comment: Advice from Twitter.  Thats... nice.

Comment: You may find that strange, but the message "you need a bazillion points before you can create a tag" leads me to tweet to our fans, not to post a plea on stack exchange. We newbies have no idea which end is up. Thanks for creating the tag!

Answer (score 4):

I've created the tag and added a brief excerpt, pending peer-review.

[blekko](/questions/tagged/blekko)

Comment: Excerpt approved.

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Now it remains to be seen if the tag sees any use... :)